# Returning MySQL results to GraphQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, graphql

I am adding GraphQL to an existing project that sits on top of a MySQL database. My framework has an ORM (codeigniter), so in a situation like this:

https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/blob/master/examples/00-hello-world/graphql.php

Say I wanted to return someone's name from the database and their user ID was passed in instead of 'message', where do I put the query? Like do i run `$this->someModel->getUser($id)` right in the resolve block and convert it to JSON? Or does graphql-php have a way of doing this more abstracted?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: There was deleted answer with just the link, just in case someone don't have rep to see it: https://medium.com/@compatt84/spatial-data-api-with-graphql-php-and-mysql-a48e8b89d4e1